# Need to double the price as per Qty in cart

Tags: magento2

Using Mageworx Shipping suite Magento2 extension i need to achieve this functionality. Can anyone guide me on this?

I have created a custom shipping rate here i want to double the rate lets say for e.g. if i purchase a product of weight 1 then if the price is 1 & qty of product in cart is 1 then if i increase product qty in cart to 2 then the price should be 2. In short as qty increse price also should double.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve that issue?